# calling function in viewDidLoad crash

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, viewdidload

Calling `parseString` crashes my application. `myOptionalString` is getting set from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in a tableview. The information is definitely get passed to this view controller.

The method also works if called from a button press. But in any life cycle method I try I get unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    if let myUnwrappedString = myOptionalString{
         print(myUnwrappedString) //<-- prints out string
         confidence.text = parseString(myUnwrappedString) //<-- unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional crash
    }        
}

//this method works if called on a button press but crashes in viewDidLoad
func parseString(myString: String)->String{
    return myString.substringFromIndex(myString.rangeOfString(" ")!.endIndex)
}
```

Comment: check confidence textfield or label connected to your storyboard

Comment: I can set the confidence.text UIlabel if I set it with myOptionalString or a hardcoded string, I don't think it's that.

Comment: Move it to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: what is the contents of `myString` when you call it from `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint before you return in parseString and check for nil

Comment: @Daniel viewDidAppear tested I get same crash

Comment: string value is "Confidence: 63%"

Comment: @Brian Is "Confidence: 63%" the value when called in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: When you save the value or printing to the console of the function `parseString` before assign it to the `confidence.text` what's the value?

Comment: when I print(myUnwrappedString) is called in viewDidload I get the string so long as the parseString(myUnwrappedString) is commented out otherwise it crashes.

Comment: Please put after your `print(myUnwrappedString) ` `print(parseString(myUnwrappedString))` and see what it's printed

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @Brian See my answer it will solve your problem

Comment: Sincere thanks everyone. I have accepted the first answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error come from your function `parseString`, let's see why. If you see carefully your function you're make a *force-unwrapping* of an optional value in your case the `myString.rangeOfString(" ")!`. This is not recommended at all.

If we pass the string `"Confidence: 63%"` to the function the function works properly and returns `"63%"`, but it works because it have the `" "` string inside, if for some reason you pass some string that don't have it it will crash (e.g `"Confidence:63%"`).

So one of the correct ways of implement this function can be using the `guard` statement using optional binding avoiding any *force-unwrapping*:

```
func parseString(myString: String) -> String? {
   guard let range = myString.rangeOfString(" ") else { return nil }
   return myString.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

In the above function you return `nil` in case of not exist the `" "` in the string and avoid the runtime error.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem lies in this line:

`myString.rangeOfString(" ")!`

`rangeOfString` returns an optional `Range<Index>?` value, meaning that if the character you are looking for is not present in the string, you will get the value `nil` in return. In other words, if there is no space in your string, you get a `nil` value for your range.

That value you then force unwrap with `!`, and then you use it to call `substringFromIndex`. This means that if the range was actually `nil`, you use that `nil` value to try to create a substring from its `endIndex`... which you cannot...so it crashes.

One way of solving this could be to use a `guard`to make sure that you actually found a range in your string. If you don't, then you just return an empty `String`...or do something else that suits your use case better.

Here is an example:

```
func parseString(myString: String)->String{
    guard let range = myString.rangeOfString(" ") else {
        return ""
    }
    return myString.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
}
```

Hope that helps you.